# React creating dynamic URL using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I am working on React and Node

Now, I want to create a dynamic URL to show user profile

In Node with EJS we could have simply done something like this

```
route.get("/:id", function(req, res) {
  playground.find({}, function (error, plyground) { //MongoDb find syntex
    if (error) {
     console.log(error);
    } else {
 playground.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments").exec(function(error, playground)  {
    if (error) {
      console.log("error -> Show route or more information about playground")
    }
    else {
      res.render("playground/show", {playground:playground, plyground:plyground})
    }
  });
}
})
})
```

Here since EJS and Node both work on the same address, hence whenever user reaches `/:id` it would find the user info from the DB and render it.

**In case of  react**, my node application is running on `localhost:8080` and react app on `localhost:3000`

I am interacting by either making API calls using axios or redirecting to react webpage address.

Now, I want to show user profile in React when someone reaches

```
 route.get("/:id", function(req, res) {
```

**Question:** So can someone please tell me how will I be able to create dynamic URL react app?

Ps: I am using react-route for navigating in my react app

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
//Remaining imports 

const route = () => {
    return(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path ="/" exact render ={(props) => <Home {...props}/>} />
        <Route path ="/signup" exact render ={(props) => <Signup {...props}/>} />
        <Route path ="/Home" exact render={(props) => <MainHomeScreen {...props}/>} />
    </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default route;
```

Answer (score 2):

On the server side we just send the data and we handle it on the client side, although you can also server side render it.

```
route.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
    const data = getDataFromDB(req.params.id);
    res.send(data);
});
```

Now on react side let's start from the routing

```
<Switch>
  <Route path ="/:id" render ={(props) => <DisplayData {...props}/>} />
</Switch>
```

Now `react-router-dom` injects a `match` prop that we can access the `id` parameter just like express.

So in `DisplayData` component we add componentDidMount lifecycle hook that will fetch the data based on the `id` parameter and set the state.

```
class DisplayData extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    axios(id)
      .then(data => this.setState({ data }))
      .catch(err => /* do something */);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 approaches (that I know off) to solve your problem and both have their pros & cons.

**Approach 1** - Use react-router routes for client side routing, and express/koa routes for server side routing.

This is basically what you have shown in your OP - use `route.get(...)` on server side and `BrowserRouter` on client side. This approach has potential to create duplicate routes handling (and in separate places) which is the biggest con IMO. The duplication however, is not a big issue since it can be minimized to a certain extent with common modules. If you prefer to use a single route definition and more of unified solution, read on to approach #2.

**Approach 2** - Use react-router routes for both server & client side routing.

Here, you'd use `StaticRouter` for server side routing and `BrowserRouter` for client side routing. This is all laid out very nicely at [react-router-dom/docs/guides/server-rendering](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/server-rendering.md). It'd be a disservice and rather pointless exercise to copy paste the code from above doc but here are some key takeaways:

- your routes are now in one common place, say `./shared/routes.js`
- your js would look something like

  ```
  // app.js
  import { routes } from "./shared/routes.js";

  const App = () => (
  <Switch>
      {routes.map(route => (
          <Route {...route} />
      ))}
  </Switch>
  );

  // server.js
  import { createServer } from "http";
  import React from "react";
  import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
  import { StaticRouter } from "react-router";
  import App from "./App";

  createServer((req, res) => {
      const context = {};

      const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
          <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
              <App />
          </StaticRouter>
      );

      if (context.url) {
          res.writeHead(301, { Location: context.url });
          res.end();
      } else {
          res.write(`
          <!doctype html>
          <div id="app">${html}</div>
          `);
          res.end();
      }
  }).listen(3000);

  // or if using express/koa
  app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
      const context = {};
      const app = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
          <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
              <App />
          </StaticRouter>
      );
      ...
  })

  // client.js
  import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
  import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
  import App from "./App";

  ReactDOM.render(
      <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
      </BrowserRouter>,
      document.getElementById("app")
  );
  ```

And if you need to fetch data or do some other hydration at server, you can use the data loading techniques described here: [Data Loading](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/server-rendering.md#data-loading).

Again, this code is not your production ready code. The key points to remember are that you need to:

- create a common route definition
- on server, render the routes using `StaticRouter`
- on client, render the same routes using `BrowserRouter`
- you can use promises or async/await to hydrate app on server using the route definition file if needed (axios, isomorphic-fetch etc. are good libraries that work on both server and client equally well).

If I misunderstood your question, and if all you want to know is how to create 2 routes that can distinguish between `/` and `/:id`; then I'd say, on top of what I mentioned above, what you need to do now is a matter of simple ordering the routes and matching with exactness. So you can define your `:/id` route first and then your `/` route to prevent collision or, modify your routes to something that is semantically correct like `users/:id`.

react-router (and most every router) will match `/` for almost everything. `exact` prop makes it conservative but that's more of a band-aid. You'd be better off by leaving `/` to your homepage and defining routes as `entity/:id` in general.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an easy or short way of explaining it but here is an example to get you going... Let's say you had a portfolio site and in there you had individual portfolio items...

Here is how you do dynamic routing with react-router:

Your router:

```
const AppRouter = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/portfolio" component={PortfolioPage} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/portfolio/:id" component={PortfolioItemPage} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Then here is your ProfolioPage:

```
const PortfolioPage = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>My Work</h1>
    <p>Checkout the stuff I've done:</p>
    <Link to="/portfolio/1">Item One</Link>
    <Link to="/portfolio/2">Item Two</Link>
  </div>
);
```

And finally your PortfolioItemPage (you can get access to that id via `{props.match.params.id}` - see below):

```
const PortfolioItem = (props) => (
  <div>
    <h1>A Thing I've Done</h1>
    <p>This page is for the item with the id of {props.match.params.id}</p>
  </div>
);
```